# How to prevent viewmodel to fire again my Loading bar

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-viewmodel, android-navigation

I have a fragment that loads a list of products, then I go to another fragment , but when I come back `Resource.Loading` is triggered again showin my progressbar

I'm using navigation components and I know that I should handle my state but my question is this.

I know that the livedata will store my data, and then when poping back to this fragment it will load it inmediatly from the livedata itself and not retrieve it again, but, it also shows my progressBar above my list of data, I know that is because my `emit(Resource.Loading())` from my viewModel, but...

Is there a way to not show this progress or not to emit that Loading state if I come back from another fragment and recreate this onActivityCreated ?

### Code

**My Fragment**

```
 override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel.fetchProductList()
            .observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

                when (it) {
                    is Resource.Loading -> {
                        showProgress()
                    }
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        hideProgress()
                        landingAdapter.itemList = it.data
                        if (landingAdapter.itemCount == 0) {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                requireContext(),
                                "No items yet",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        }
                        landingAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                    is Resource.Failure -> {
                        hideProgress()
                    }
                }
            })
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
fun fetchProductList() = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        emit(Resource.Loading())
        try{
            val getProductList = repo.getProductList()
            emit(getProductList)
        }catch (e:Exception){
            emit(Resource.Failure(e))
        }
    }
```

At this point is where I think that emiting again `Resource.Loading()` when recreating my fragment on a popBackstack is showing me again my progressDialog

I have tried using the Event wrapper but it also does the same

### Edit

Since I'm using `livedata-ktx` , I dont want to load my data whitin my viewmodel constructor, instead I want to handle this just once at my fragment

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding a fourth state `Resource.Idle` that emits whenever the user navigates away while the current state is `Resource.Loading`, and when observing the state, take no action when it's value is `Resource.Idle`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is very rasonable and I like it, the thing is that I will need to nest a new observer inside my first call and I dont want to do it that way, thanks for your answer

Comment: Alright. another suggestion would be to consume  the `Resource.Loading` object so its only used once. if your are interested check this: https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/Event.kt

Comment: I think another `state of sealed class` is redundant this particular case @CoffeeBreak @Mohsin

Answer (score 0):

`fetchProductList()` *is* `function` **NOT** a `variable` calling it `returns` new `LiveData<Resource>` object. Instead try not using function:-

```
val productListLiveData: LiveData<Resource> = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
    emit(Resource.Loading())
    try {
        val getProductList = repo.getProductList()
        emit(getProductList)
    } catch (e:Exception){
        emit(Resource.Failure(e))
    }
}
```

Observe it in the `fragment`.

Comment: Actually , I'm passing a parameter to it that I didnt specify in the question, soryy

Comment: Then u can directly pass the parameter to `viewModel` using `viewModelFactory` , creating a new liveData object everytime using builder lambda would be bad practice @CoffeeBreak

Comment: I have a viewModelFactory already to inject my repo inside the viewmodel, what I need to do is not to trigger the progressBar when emit(Resource.Loading()) is hit inside that function

Comment: If the dependency graph is created , within the fragment , the `parameters` can also be injected along with the `repo` @see [BindsInstance](https://dagger.dev/api/2.10/dagger/BindsInstance.html)